# Sorting multiline expressions

Tags: regular-expression, sort

I have a file that contains entries that are indexed by a key:

```
\newglossaryentry{[alpha key]}
{
    [some lines with arbitrary content]
}
```

Two entries may be separated by one or more lines. How would I sort these entries based on their key? A subsidiary question is what regular expression for this pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -0ne 'print join "\\", sort split(/^\\/m)' input.txt
```

This is based on the [Sort file by group of lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524048/sort-file-by-group-of-lines) answer linked to by @αғsнιη.

It splits the entire input file into an array, using the regexp `^\` as the delimiter.  Then it prints the sorted array, with the array elements joined by a single `\` character.

The join is necessary, because it puts back the `\` characters that were removed during the split operation.

---

Note: this script doesn't care at all about the contents of the glossary definitions.  All it does is split the input into an array based on lines beginning with `\`.

This means that if there are any input lines **before** the first `\newglossary` entry they will be printed in sort order (because they become array element 0).   If there are no such lines, then array element 0 is empty, and is printed first (because the empty string sorts before everything else) but produces no visible ouput (because it's empty).

If there are any lines  of text **after** the last `\newglossary` entry, they will be printed wherever that entry is sorted to because the script considers them to be **part of that entry**.

The same thing happens if there is arbitrary text between two entries - those lines become part of the first of those two entries.